# I need to find $P (W_{1} + W_{2} \mid W_{3} = 3)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-probability

$W_{t}$ is Wiener process.
I came to a conclusion, that I need to find conditional density. $f_{X|Y} (x, y)$.
To do that I need to find $f_{X, Y} (x, y)$
I tried to express both sides somehow, so that they are independent (or divide into a sum, so that both parts are independent) but no luck.

How can I find it? I mean, is there a dumb but working approach here? Or I should keep trying to find some way to express $W_{I}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $(W_1+W_2,W_3)\sim N(0, \Sigma)$, where
$$
\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3 \\
3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
[Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2) $W_1+W_2\mid W_3=w\sim N(w, 2)$.

Comment: Seems like a valid solution, thanks! But do you have any insights about how to get that result from Wikipedia? I mean, how can one find $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, where X and Y are not independent ?

Comment: In your case $W_1$, $W_2$, and $W_3$ are jointly Gaussian. This helps to find the rest.